# Finding a Doob decomposition

Tags: martingales

> Let $(M_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a square integrable martingale and $(X_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ iid square integrable random variables with $\mathbb{E}X_1=1$. Show $M_n := \Pi_{k=1}^n X_k$ is a square integrable martingale and determine its quadratic variation.

I tried $$E(M_{n+1}|\mathcal{A}_n)=E(\Pi_{k=1}^{n+1} X_k|\mathcal{A}_n)=\Pi_{k=1}^nX_k E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{A}_n)=M_n\cdot1$$
and $$EM_n^2=E((\Pi_{k=1}^{n}X_k)^2)=\Pi_{k=1}^{n}E(X_k^2)<\infty$$
So $M_n$ is a square integrable martingale and $M_n^2$ a submartingale. I wanted to use Doob decomposition:
$$\langle M_n\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n(E(M_i^2|\mathcal{A_{i-1}})-M^2_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^n(E(\Pi_{k=1}^{i}X_i^2|\mathcal{A_{i-1}})-\Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_k^2)= ...$$

I do not know how to continue... what can I do now? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a good start. To finish, by independence,
$$
E(\Pi_{k=1}^{i}X_i^2|\mathcal{A_{i-1}})=\Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_i^2\cdot E(X_i^2|\mathcal A_{i-1}) = \Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_i^2\cdot E(X_i^2)=\Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_i^2\cdot (\sigma^2+1),
$$
so
$$
E(\Pi_{k=1}^{i}X_i^2|\mathcal{A_{i-1}})-\Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_k^2=\sigma^2\cdot \Pi_{k=1}^{i-1}X_k^2=\sigma^2M_{i-1}^2.
$$
where $\sigma^2:=E(X_1^2)-1$. Therefore $\langle M\rangle_n=\sigma^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}M_k^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Yup. Reconciling this with my previously wrong answer I learned a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I thank Snoop for a comment and John Dawkins for his other answer which led me to elaborate a bit to show what can go wrong (and in fact was going wrong in my earlier versions):

Since the $X_k$ are i.i.d.
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathbb E[X_k^2]&={\rm Var}[X_1]+1=:\sigma^2+1\,.
\end{align}
The quadratic variation is the [unique increasing predictable
process](https://mathoverflow.net/a/145237/340165) $\langle M\rangle_n$
such that $M_n^2-\langle M\rangle_n$ is a martingale. For a discrete process predictable means that at $n$ it has to be ${\cal A}_{n-1}$-measurable.

Notation:
\begin{align}
A_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sigma^2M_k^2\,,\tag{2}\\
B_n&:=\sum_{k=1}^n(M_k-M_{k-1})^2\,,\tag{3}\\
C_n&:=\mathbb E\Big[B_n\Big|{\cal A}_{n-1}\Big]\tag{4}
\end{align}

- When $\sigma>0$ ***only*** the two processes $M_n^2-A_n\,,M_n^2-B_n$ are martingales, and only $A_n$ is the *predictable* quadratic variation $\langle M\rangle_n\,$.
- $B_n$ is not predictable.
- $C_n$ is predictable but not necessarily increasing and does not make $M_n^2-C_n$ a martingale.

Proof.
Using the i.i.d properties of the $X_i\,,$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}^2|{\cal A}_n]&=\mathbb E\Big[\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k^2\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]=
\mathbb E[X_{n+1}^2]\prod_{k=1}^nX_k^2=\sigma^2M^2_n+M^2_n\,.\tag{5}
\end{align}
Since taking the conditional expectation twice does not change the result,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\Big[C_{n+1}\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]&=\mathbb E\Big[B_{n+1}\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]=\underbrace{\mathbb E\Big[(M_{n+1}-M_n)^2\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]}_{(*)}+B_n\,.\tag{6}
\end{align}
Because $M_n$ is a martingale we can further develop the (*) term in (6):
\begin{align}
(*)&=\mathbb E\Big[M_{n+1}^2 \,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]-2M_n^2+M_n^2
\stackrel{(5)}{=}\sigma^2M^2_n\,.\tag{7}
\end{align}
Therefore, by (5) and (7),
$$
\mathbb E\Big[M_{n+1}^2-C_{n+1}\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]=M^2_n-\color{red}{B_n}\,,\tag{8}
$$
that is, $M_n^2-C_n$ is $\color{red}{\rm not}$ a martingale.

The proof that $M_n^2-B_n$ is a martingale is the same. Use (5)-(7).

To see that $M_n^2-A_n$ is a martingale we only have to observe that, since $A_{n+1}$ is ${\cal A}_n$-measurable by definition,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\Big[A_{n+1}\,\Big|{\cal A}_n\Big]&=\sigma ^2M_n^2+ A_n\tag{9}
\end{align}
trivially holds. Combining (5) with (9) shows that $M_n^2-A_n$ is a martingale.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$
***Remark.***
The situation in the discrete case is a bit analogous to discontinuous processes. We know that
for the Poisson process $N$ the predictable quadratic variation is $\langle N\rangle_t=\lambda t\,.$ But there is also the quadratic variation
$$
[N]_t=\sum_{s\le t}(N_s-N_{s-})^2=\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta N_s)^2=\sum_{s\le t}\Delta N_s=N_t\tag{10}
$$
which makes $N_t-[N]_t$  a martingale. But $[N]_t$ is not predictable.

Comment: Hello @Kurt, shouldn't we have $\langle M\rangle_{n+1}=\sum_{k\leq n}M_{k}^2(E[X_1^2]-1)$? Also shouldn't $\langle M \rangle_n$ be predictable? I may be mistaken though

Comment: @Snoop Not at all. Thanks for making a very good point. I think in the discrete (like in the discontinuous) case there are two versions of QV. I am sure about the discontinuous case. We know that for the Poisson process $N$ the predictable QV is $\langle N\rangle_t=\lambda t$ and the QV $[N]_t=\sum_{s\le t}(N_s-N_{s-})^2=N_t$. Both make $N_t^2$ a martingale when subtracted. Do you want to formulate a second answer?

Comment: Not necessary; just checking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We just introduced Doob decomposition. "The quadratic variation is the [unique increasing predictable
process](https://mathoverflow.net/a/145237/340165) $\langle M\rangle_n$
such that $M_n^2-\langle M\rangle_n$ is a martingale." I have never heard of this. Why does this hold?

Comment: In fact: to call that a quadratic variation is more common in continuous time processes but what Nate Eldrege wrote in MO is sound. The Doob decomposition comes in two flavours. The one we use here is for [submartingales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_decomposition_theorem#Corollary) which -according to Doob- can be uniquely decomposed into a martingale and an increasing predictable process. We know that $M_n^2$ is a submartingale. Therefore there is nothing wrong with calling its increasing predictable component a quadratic variation. ...

Comment: ... This is exactly what we do in continuous time processes.